# Attempting to Multithread URL Connections to Reduce Load Time

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, urlconnection

Snip from the main

```
    public void xmlQuery(String x,String y){

    //takes spaces off the input
    String k = x.trim();
    String v = y.trim();

    //calling the threading class
    for(int i = 0; i<18; i++){
        callThreading.threadedCall(i,k,v);
    }
}
```

The threading class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class callThreading {
public static void threadedCall(int th, String k, String v){
    switch(th){
        case 0:Thread currentThread0 = new Thread(threadedCall0(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 1:Thread currentThread1 = new Thread(threadedCall1(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 2:Thread currentThread2 = new Thread(threadedCall2(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 3:Thread currentThread3 = new Thread(threadedCall3(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 4:Thread currentThread4 = new Thread(threadedCall4(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 5:Thread currentThread5 = new Thread(threadedCall5(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 6:Thread currentThread6 = new Thread(threadedCall6(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 7:Thread currentThread7 = new Thread(threadedCall7(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 8:Thread currentThread8 = new Thread(threadedCall8(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 9:Thread currentThread9 = new Thread(threadedCall9(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 10:Thread currentThread10 = new Thread(threadedCall10(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 11:Thread currentThread11 = new Thread(threadedCall11(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 12:Thread currentThread12 = new Thread(threadedCall12(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 13:Thread currentThread13 = new Thread(threadedCall13(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 14:Thread currentThread14 = new Thread(threadedCall14(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 15:Thread currentThread15 = new Thread(threadedCall15(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 16:Thread currentThread16 = new Thread(threadedCall16(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
        case 17:Thread currentThread17 = new Thread(threadedCall17(th, k, v)).start();
            break;
    }
}

public static Runnable threadedCall0(int th, String k, String v){
    System.out.println("call0");
    return null;
}   
public static Runnable threadedCall1(int th, String k, String v){
    System.out.println("call1");
    return null;
}
}
```

...and the methods go on to threadedCall17

CODE EDITED to reflect MVCE as best I can.

I am trying to multithread all my URL connections at the same time so that load time of my program is reduced. Current load time is ~11 seconds. The parameter int th in the callThreading class is passed from a for loop in the main method and int th goes from 0++ to 17.

It has been pointed out to me there would be diminishing return if I were to do all 18 calls at once. I will tinker with different rates once the threading is working.

The code listed results in “Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread” errors.

If I am lacking any detail, let me know.

Comment: 1)  Questions that ask for help with code should include the code in the Question (not as a pastebin link).  2) Asking us to review ~700 lines of code is a bit much.  3) There looks like a lot of cut-and-paste coding in there.  Ughh.  4)  You said it is a mess.  I agree.  Why are you asking us to read your mess?  5) Write an MVCE ....  with the emphasis on the M.

Comment: 1) Didn't want to junk up the post with a large chunk of code. 2) The only relevant code is before the cut and pasting. Only included it all so there was no confusion. 3) There is, it's what I tried to get the threading to work. 4) I have a view, model, and the class in the pastebin.

Comment: Rules are rules.  Pastebin links are grounds for Question closure.  Sorry.  As for the rest, nobody here is likely to even try to read 700 lines of code to work out what is and what isn't relevant.

Comment: MVCE =/= MVC [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Pastebin removed.

Comment: Your question is based on a fallacy. The network is not multi-threaded. Starting 17 downloads in parallel will not be 17 times as fast as doing them sequentially. All that happens is that the available bandwidth to the target is divided up among the 17 connections, 1/17th each.

Comment: Is this true even with high bandwidth? 17 calls at once using more bandwidth instead of 17 sequential calls? What you say makes sense, I'm just making sure.

Comment: Also, implemented MVCE as best I can

Comment: It's true if the peer is saturating the bandwidth, and if the peer isn't saturating the bandwidth your problem is compute-bound at the peer so there is nothing to be gained for a different reason.

Comment: Could sending 2 requests at a time be reasonable, or does this need to be sequential?

Comment: It doesn't 'need' to be sequential at all, but you need to moderate your expectations. Try 2,3,4,... until you get to diminishing returns, which could be at 2,3,4,...

Comment: I'll make sure to try that. Much appreciated. For now I am dealing with an error described in the comments of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thread currentThread1 = new Thread(...).start();
```

`Thread.start()` doesn't return a `Thread`. It is a void method. So you can't use the result to initialize anything.

You could solve this in various ways, but the simplest is:

```
Thread currentThread1 = new Thread(...);
currentThread1.start();
```

I don't really see why you have all those `Thread` variables. One would do. Then you could move the `start()` call to after the `switch` statement:

```
Thread currentThread;
switch th)
{
case 0:
    currentThread = new Thread(...);
    break;
// ...
default:
    // unreachable, just to shut up the compiler
    return;
}
currentThread.start();
```

Comment: I solved the error with your suggestion, thank you. 
Now the for loop in the main class seems to be waiting for a return, as there is a pause between each time it calls the threadedCall method. How do I get rid of this pause?

Comment: I'm going to revert to just using a for loop to run the code as one method. Threading is resulting in null values in the hashtable I am writing the XML to. Will come back to threading after my professor goes over it, if he goes over it in this course. Thank you for your time. Your answer got me the furthest.

Answer (score 2):

First comment.  Your `threadCall` method is odd.  Each time it is called, it creates 18 Thread objects, starts one of them and throws the rest away.  Odd.  However, that won't cause a threading bottleneck.  (The unused threads never get started ...)

There is also some poor coding in the `threadedCallNN` methods, but nothing that would cause a threading bottleneck.

Basically, nothing in the code you have shown us explains the problem.

In the absence of an MCVE **that we could run for ourselves** we can only guess as to why you are not getting a speed up.  A couple of possible explanations:

- The limiting factor could be the throughput of your end-to-end network connection.
- The limiting factor could be the rate at which the remote server can deliver data.
- The remote server could be rate limiting you; e.g. by processing your requests one at a time.

If the real explanation is any one of those, then multi-threading won't help.

You may be able to get some insights by adding some tracing.  For example, try to see if the threads are actually attempting to read data at the same time, or if something is causing them to do something one thread at a time.

Comment: Code edited, thanks for pointing out that I am making multiple dummy threads.

Comment: Snip from the main added. Now I am getting 
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread" from the bits of code in the switch statement